# Find the first occurrence of an odd and count them

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;

public class FirstOddOccurrence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {2, 4, 6, 7, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 7, 7};
        int i;

        display(x);

        System.out.printf("# Occurrences of first odd = %3d\n", firstOddCount(x));
    }

    private static void display(int[] x) {
        int i;

        System.out.print("Array: ");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (i < x.length - 1)
                System.out.printf("%3d, ", x[i]);
            else
                System.out.printf("%3d\n", x[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int odd(int[] x) {
        int i;
        int y;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            y = x[i] % 2;
            if (y == 1) {
                return x[i];
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return x[i];
    }

    public static int firstOddCount(int x[]) {
        int i;
        int c = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] == odd(x))
                c++;

        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find the first occurrence of an odd number in the array that has been provided. What is wrong with my program? I can't seem to get the program to count the first odd occurrences.

Comment: What output do you expect and what are you getting instead?

Answer (score 2):

Your code here:

```
if (y == 1) {
    return x[i];
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

does not work - if a tested number is even, you immediately return `0`. Instead you want to skip these even numbers and wait until an odd number comes up. In the end, if you don't find any odd number, you return `0`. Here is the corrected version of `odd()`:

```
int i;
int y;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    y = x[i] % 2;
    if (y == 1) {
        return x[i];
    }
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Andr's solution fixes your issue; odd(x) will return 0 if x[0] is even, and x[0] if it is odd.

You could also improve firstOddCount like so: odd(x) will always return the same value, so only calculate it once.

```
public static int firstOddCount(int x[]) {
   int firstOdd = odd(x);
   int c=0;
   for(int i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
       if (x[i]==firstOdd)
            c++;
   }
   return c;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your particular problem is that you return `0` if you find an even number. That means that the list `{2, 4, 6, 8, 1}` will give you `0`, rather than `1`, as the first odd number.

What you *should* do is ignore leading even numbers and continue to process the list.

However, the way you've organised your program, you're processing the first all-even part of the list twice, once in `odd()`  to find the first odd number, then again in `firstOddCount()` to count how many of that number there are - that's *totally* unnecessary.

Once you find the first odd number, I think you can be *reasonably* certain that number (or any *other* odd number for that matter) does not exist in the space you've already searched. Otherwise *it* would have been the first odd number. Hence it makes little sense to go back and look at that initial part of the list again.

A way in which you can easily just process the list *once* is as follows:

```
public static int firstOddCount (int numbers[]) {
    // Find first odd number or end of list.

    int idx = 0, len = numbers.length;
    while ((idx < len) && ((numbers[idx] % 2) == 0)
        idx++;

    // If at end of list, everything is even => count(first(odd)) is 0.

    if (idx == len)
        return 0;

    // Otherwise, start counting from current position.

    int count = 1, oddnum = numbers[idx];
    while (++idx < len)
        if (numbers[idx] == oddnum)
            count++;

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get one element from group you should use 'break' when your condition matched first time else it will give all...